# Why does this show that every solution exists for all $t\in (-\infty,+\infty)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

> > Show that every solution of the system
> >     $$
> > \frac{dx}{dt}=y,\quad\frac{dy}{dt}=x-x^7,\qquad(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,
> > $$
> >     is defined for all $t\in (-\infty,+\infty)$.

The given solution is the following:

The Hamiltonian $H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^8}{8}$ is conserved:
$$
\frac{dH}{dt}=(x^7-x)y+y(x-x^7)=0.
$$
Therefore $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ remain bounded for all $t$ (otherwise $H(x,y)$ would grow). Hence $(x(t),y(t))$ is globally defined.

---

I cannot fully understand this argumentation...

Of course, if $(x(t),y(t))$ is a solution, the Hamiltonian is constant along $(x(t),y(t))$.

But does this tell anything about boundedness of the solution?

In fact, if $H$ would grow, i.e. $\frac{dH}{dt}>0$, then $(x(t),y(t))$ would be no solution, since the Hamiltonian is constant along solutions.

Comment: Look at what $H$ is. If (at least) one of $x,y$ were unbounded, then $H(x(t),y(t))$ would be unbounded. Hence the solution must remain bounded for its entire lifetime.

Comment: Have you heard about solution continuation theorems? Take at look at them: using the fact that level sets are bounded might allow you to fulfill conditions of these theorems.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure that I understood your reasoning correctly, but there are Hamiltonians with non-bounded level sets.

Comment: @Evgeny But for _this particular_ $H(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{2} - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^8}{8}$, all level sets are compact.

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not understand. It is $H(x,y)=\text{const}$ if $(x,y)$ is a solution. What is the level set?

Comment: @Rhjg A level set of $H$ is $H^{-1}(c) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : H(x,y) = c\}$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Sometimes that's also called a fibre of $H$, but that terminology is used more often in other areas.

Comment: So if $H(x,y)=c$ for some constant $c$, we here have that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ must be bounded? That is the level set has to be bounded? How to see this exactly? It is enough to show that each level sets are bounded?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I am just confused by part "If (at least) one of $x$, $y$ were unbounded, then $H(x(t), y(t))$ would be unbounded". It's Hamiltonian: it stays constant along trajectory, it neither grows nor decreases. Sorry again :)

Comment: @Evgeny I think it would be better to say that each level set is bounded and hence $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ must be bounded hence each solution $(x(t),y(t))$ exists for all $t$. Or?

Comment: @Evgeny And that $u(t) = H(x(t),y(t))$ is constant in particular implies that $u$ is bounded. But if one of $x,y$ were unbounded, then $u$ would be unbounded. That's a contradiction. Hence $x$ and $y$ are both bounded. The argument without using a contradiction is "The level sets of $H$ are compact, hence bounded, and the curve $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ stays in one level set, therefore it is bounded".

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the argument using the contradiction is the better one here since if we use the other one one would have to prove that each level set is bounded which is not that easy as far as I see.

Comment: @DanielFischer Consider Hamiltonian $H(x, y) = \frac{y^2}{2} +\frac{x^2}{2}-x^3$. Consider [level set](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y^2%2F2+%2B+x^2%2F2+-+x^3%2F3+%3D+0) $H(x, y) = 0$. You say that if $(x(t), y(t))$ were unbounded, then $u(t) = H(x(t), y(t))$ would be unbounded. Okay, trajectory is unbounded, but $u(t) \equiv 0$. Maybe I don't understand your reasoning, but for me it feels wrong (because I have this counterexample).

Comment: @Evgeny We are looking at a specific situation. We have the Hamiltonian $H(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{2} - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^8}{8}$. For **this** Hamiltonian the level sets are bounded, and hence the trajectories are bounded. Of course that doesn't hold for all systems.

Comment: @DanielFischer I totally agree with reasoning using boundedness of level sets. I just don't agree with the parallel reasoning that starts with "if $x$ or $y$ were bounded ... ". I think I understand it better now, but it uses (at least implicitly) that level sets are bounded in this case. But why should we need this additional step when we can just use that trajectories lie on level sets?

Comment: @Rhjg In the answer there is already a proof of boundedness of level sets.

Comment: @Evgeny There's no "parallel reasoning", I just phrased it as an indirect proof (because of the "otherwise $H(x,y)$ would grow" in the solution). I hope you don't disagree with the reasoning that "if $\gamma$ is an unbounded curve and $F$ a function whose sublevel sets are bounded, then $F\circ\gamma$ is unbounded" [if we only require bounded level sets of $F$, we can only deduce that $F\circ \gamma$ is non-constant, it need not be unbounded, but for the $H$ under consideration here it's easy to see that $H(x,y)\to+\infty$ for $\lVert(x,y)\rVert\to+\infty$, so we have bounded sublevel sets].

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, I've already understood that reasoning before I wrote my previous comment :) and this kind of indirect proof was a little bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Take any particular solution, with initial conditions $x(a)=b,y(a)=c$.  Then $H(x,y)=\frac{c^2}2-\frac{b^2}2+\frac{b^8}8=d$ for all $t$.  If $x(t)^2$ ever got above $2d+3/4$, there would be no possible value for $y(t)$.
So $x(t)$ is bounded.  $y(t)$ is also bounded, for similar reasons.
Both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ have bounded derivative, so they can be extended into the future.